# Is the @input() tag available for classes in angular?

Tags: angular

I'm watching some videos about Angular 2 on the Microsoft Virtual Academy and there is a lot of slides who show a class tagged with the `@input()` attribute. The first time I saw this I thank it was a mistake, but now I saw at least 3 or 4 differents slides on differents videos with a class tagged with `@input()`.

I searched on the official documentation, and I didn't found any class with an `@input()` tag.

Is this some mistakes or it's possible to mark a class as *inputeable* in angular 2 ?

Some slides containing this :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Input()` doesn't make sense on classes, only on fields (or getters/setters) of components or directives.

In your screenshot `@Input()` should be `@Injectable()` instead.